# QWebView doesn't perform redirection when loading Facebook dialog

Tags: facebook, qt, qwebview

I have a sort of Facebook client written with a help of Qt. It uses QWebView to access Facebook feed dialog. Facebook api redirects to the login page and after authorization allows to post a message.

The problem is it can be done correctly only the first time I use it in my app. The next time QWebView only loads html with redirect scripts and do nothing (but the first time it yields loading of the login page).

Does anyone know what kind of problem is it?

update: 
It appears any javascript content won't work, not only redirect scripts.

Answer (score 1):

is Javascript enabled like this ?

QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);

Comment: New to Qt, but that looks right. Except that the manual says that Javascript is enabled by default: "Enables or disables the running of JavaScript programs. This is enabled by default" http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum